# Setting Java CLASSPATH doesn't work but -cp does

Tags: java, windows, classpath

So, here's the problem I encountered. I wrote a simple .bat file to run weka on some data sets I had but Java recently updated itself and it stopped working. My old code was this:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET CLASSPATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\weka.jar"
FOR /r %%I IN (*.arff) DO (
    ECHO Running %%~nI.arff
    java weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t %%~nI.arff -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 1,3,4,5" -W weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -x 10 >> results.txt
    ECHO >> results.txt
)
```

This worked before and it did the job I asked of it. However, after the java update, I kept getting the error "Could not find or load main class weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier". I couldn't figure it out because the directory names and class names were exactly correct. So, I changed the code to this:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET CLASSPATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\weka.jar"
FOR /r %%I IN (*.arff) DO (
    ECHO Running %%~nI.arff
    java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\weka.jar" weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t %%~nI.arff -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 1,3,4,5" -W weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -x 10 >> results.txt
    ECHO >> results.txt
)
```

And it worked again. Can anyone tell me why this happened? The only thing I can think of is that the Java update isn't playing nice with itself somehow. Any insight would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Try without the quotes: `SET CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\weka.jar`

Comment: The error shows that you were trying to execute the class `FilteredClassiifer`, instead of `FilteredClassifier`.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry that was a typo on my end, not part of the error

Comment: @user2864740 Tried without the quotes and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET WEKA_HOME=c:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASPATH%;%WEKA_HOME%\weka.jar
bash learn.sh
```

Comment: Please also add an explanation of how and why this will help